# Launchd process stalls Firefox startup on Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, osx-yosemite, launchd

I have long wait times up to 2 to 3 minutes when starting web browsers Firefox and Safari. Looked at Activity monitor and saw "launchd" taking up 98% of memory. CPU Time was 1.40.93 at the time. I have to completely shut down to get going again. 
Not an expert in checking into these issues. Thanks for any help willing to learn.